# android custom keyboard selecting a key from popup when removed finger

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, soft-keyboard, android-custom-keyboard

i want to detect button in my popup when i removed my finger on it.

i want popup like AOSP or a.i.type keyboard.

this is my code for show popup .

```
@Override
public void onPress(int i) {
    View custom = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.popupkey, new FrameLayout(this));
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(this);
    popup.setContentView(custom);
    popup.setWidth(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setHeight(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.showAtLocation(keyboardView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);

    keyboardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(popup != null && motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                popup.dismiss();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: didi you find any solution?